# c++ vector insertion and reading

Tags: c++, vector, fifo

I am inserting elements with push_back in a vector. I want to read the data in FIFO and using iterator assigned to begin of vector. Is there any other approach of reading data in FIFO in a vector?

Comment: Are you trying to build a queue? I.e. do you remove the elements after reading?

Comment: yes I am removing by erase function using iterator.

Comment: Then use deque instead of vector as suggested by @Didac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a `std::deque()` and its `pop_front()` method.

Comment: I did not see pop_front(). Is it defined for a vector?

Comment: Not in vector, use `std::deque` instead of a `std::vector`, which has both front and back references which may give you what you want.

Comment: Check that the `empty()` method returns `false`.

Comment: @AvbAvb All standard containers have an `empty` function, which in fact is a predicate `isEmpty`.  And both `vector` and `deque` have a `front()` method.

Comment: @AvbAvb All of the functions of the standard containers have the same thread safety requirements.  If you access a single container from more than one thread, and any thread mutates it, _all_ accesses must be externally synchronized.  And of course, you don't want to release the synchronization between the moment you check for empty, and the moment you actually remove the element.

Answer (score 0):

The code would be:

```
auto value = myvector[0];
myvector.erase(myvector.begin());
```

However, removing elements from the beginning (or somewhere in between) is slow, because it must copy the whole array. Access is fast though: `vector` allows random access (i.e. access by any explicit index) in O(1) (i.e. constant access time, i.e. very fast).

But another container structure instead of `vector` might make more sense for you, e.g. `list` or `deque`. Some STL implementations (or other framework) also have something like `rope` which is in many cases the best of both worlds.

Comment: That's LIFO, not FIFO.

Comment: In practice, unless the elements are extremely expensive to copy, or there are many millions of them, `std::vector` is likely to outperform `std::deque` (and will almost certainly outperform `std::list`).  The convenience of `pop_front()`, however, speaks for `std::deque`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: By convenience, you mean that it is just shorter to type instead of the two commands (access + `erase`)? If `vector` would be faster, does that justify the `deque` usage then?

Comment: @Albert It's shorter to type, but more importantly, it expresses exactly what is wanted, in a single word, rather than requiring the reader to figure it out.  For this reason, I'd go with `deque` unless I had performance issues.  (In my case, performance was an issue, and using `std::vector<char>` was significantly faster than `std::deque<char>`, where the maximum size never got over about 10.  For larger queues, with objects which are more expensive to copy, the difference will be less, and at some point will probably favor `deque`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements of a vecotr just like you would access the elements of an array:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
// Excluded: push items onto vec
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
  // Example:
  std::cout << vec[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special to pay attention to.  To insert, use
`push_back`, to extract, you need something like:

```
if ( !fifo.empty() ) {
    ValueType results = fifo.front();
    fifo.erase( fifo.begin() );
}
```

(Don't forget to check for empty before trying to remove an
element.)

An important point to remember is that both `push_back` and
in some cases `erase` can invalidate iterators, so you don't
want to keep iterators into the underlying vector hanging
around.